# Clipboard integration with GNU Screen and Mac OS X Terminal

Tags: mac, command-line, terminal, gnu-screen, clipboard

I am using GNU Screen on Terminal. Is there a way to use what I copied in GNU Screen
into OS X's clipboard? I'm running

- Mac OS X 10.6.2
- Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06

**Edit**: I was thinking about how to pass the content that is copied in copy mode in Screen to `pbcopy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `writebuf` screen command to write the buffer out to a file, then use e.g. `pbcopy < /tmp/bufferfile`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm edit copy mode bindings to to copy paste buffer contents into OS X clipboard automatically.

```
# copy the screen pastbuffer to the MacOSX pastebord
bufferfile screen/screen-exchange
bindkey -m ' ' eval 'stuff \040' 'writebuf' 'exec sh -c "/usr/bin/pbcopy < screen/screen-exchange"'
bindkey -m Y   eval 'stuff Y'    'writebuf' 'exec sh -c "/usr/bin/pbcopy < screen/screen-exchange"'
bindkey -m W   eval 'stuff W'    'writebuf' 'exec sh -c "/usr/bin/pbcopy < screen/screen-exchange"'
```